# Web SSO solution that's easy to implement?

Tags: java, security, single-sign-on

I'm looking at a SSO (Single Sign On) solution to fit our relatively simple use case.

Website1  - currently authenticates with database user table.
Website 2 [new] - wants to use the same authentication information and when user clicks link to website1 they shouldn't have to re-login.

Website1 is J2EE based running on Websphere. 
Website 2 is .Net based hosted by external company.

Ideally looking to keep the current user table as the user directory and have time out of session across applications and password expiry.

Any suggestions on 'simple' SSO solution, trying to justify it against rolling our own.

Comment: Sorry I should ellaborate on Website 2. It's hosted externally and is a content management system from a external company. We are paying them for the CMS services, host content, documents etc and do some intergrate work for the authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Central Authentication Service project (CAS) on a couple of projects. It was simple, easy to grasp and implement as of version 1.x.

CAS is an authentication system originally created by Yale University but now part of the Jasig Community.

[Jasig Community CAS homepage](http://www.jasig.org/cas)

[DeveloperWorks article on CAS from 2003](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-singlesign/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can run both services under Apache, this worth a look: http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/

Answer (score 0):

I am sure below solution will meet your expectation.

> http://webmoli.com/2009/08/29/single-sign-on-in-java-platform/

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more general solution that is very popular these days is [OpenID](http://openid.net/developers/). You can use your user table as an OpenID provider, and set up all your websites as OpenID consumers.

Benefits:

- Simple
- Widely used
- Extensible, later you can allow more providers or add more consumers
- Implementations in [many languages](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/)